# Encode/Decode Original mail body to readable foreign (Chinese) character

Tags: php, imap, mime

An email text in Gmail looks like this, they are mixed with English and Chinese characters:

```
中中字 smile
```

When I click "show original" in Gmail, the body looks like this:

```
=E4=B8=AD=E4=B8=AD=E5=AD=97 smile
```

As you can see, the English part ('smile') looks the same either from Gmail front face or original mail, but the Chinese characters seemed to be handled.

**Question:** 
**How do I encode/decode Marsians in original mail body to readables ?**

Many thanks ~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a hexdecimal representation of their unicode values (E4B8AD, etc)

```
$string = "=E4=B8=AD=E4=B8=AD=E5=AD=97 smile";

$string = preg_replace_callback(
    "/=([a-zA-Z0-9]{2})/", 
    function ($match) {
        return hex2bin($match[1]);
    },
    $string
);

var_dump($string);
```

will result in `string(15) "中中字 smile"`

Comment: No need to use regexps for that. The function [quoted_printable_decode](http://us2.php.net/quoted_printable_decode) can do the conversion, and also handles line breaks etc as specified in RFC 2045.

Comment: Should have known that there is a native php function for that... :)